# How to i find in skype if my friend removed me if dont?

Tags: skype

How to i find in skype my friend if removed me if not ?..

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question is very poor quality. It will be very helpful for you to take the **[tour]** to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Skype](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-archive/How-To-Know-If-You-Have-Been-Deleted-by-a-Contact/td-p/176610) forum

> If you have been deleted by a person from their contact list, you will
>   not be able to see their online status and mood message.  So when you
>   check their name in your contact list, what you will see is the gray
>   Skype icon with a question mark inside
>
> When you open their IM/Call window, you will see the This Contact Has
>   Not Shared Their Contact Details With You notification
>
> When you hover the cursor over their name in the View Profile window,
>   you will not be able to see their Last Seen information.  Instead, the
>   notification This Contact Has Not Shared Their Contact Details With
>   You﻿ will also be displayed

.